# Running a java program in VScode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I start coding java with VScode recently. I have a simple problem. The problem is that I do not want the output to be like that. In other words, I do not want the program to run in the terminal as shown below. I just want the statements to be printed alone. Here, I just want (Hello world) only to be printed with nothing else. I googled how to run a java program and I found that the output must appear in either OUTPUT or DEBUG CONSOLE.

Can anyone please help me?. NOTE: I installed java 14 as well as all needed extensions in VScode for java.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your code needn't input data, you can add this in the launch.json:

```
"console": "internalConsole"
```

The default value is:

```
"console": "integratedTerminal"
```

I do not suggest install the 'Code-Runner' extension, because it will compile the java file under the same folder of the java file, and mix them up.

And I recommended you to get used to the outputs, the outputs can provide useful information, let you know what's exactly the vscode does. If you run into some problems, you will need this information to help you to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can just press Command F5 (Mac) or other keybindings (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings). This runs the program in your IDE. Otherwise, you can create a launch.json file to configure your debugging.

Comment: F5 does not do anything. All outputs (old and new) appear together in the terminal. I got stuck with this link.

Comment: @HusseinEid, you can use the trash button on the top of the terminal, or you can clear the stale workspace. Otherwise, you can always press Control C (on Mac) and type 'clear' into the terminal to wipe the previous session.

Comment: I want the output to be like that in Intellij IDEA or NetBeans. All I want is to get ride of powershell. I actually do not understand you but I will try.

Comment: I hope this works https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging

Comment: I see that you are trying to remove the unnecessary outputs in the terminal while debugging

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is follow the instruction in [Run and Debug Java in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging) to setup a launch.json file. This defines how your code is launched and where the output from that debug session goes. You can customize the Debug output that appears by adding and configuring the [User Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging#_user-settings) for the Microsoft Java Debugger

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things which you can do:

If you have installed all necessary extension packs, then the editor would display an option to Run & Debug the class on the code itself. (rare cases but it appeared while working in Linux)

Else type `javac <name.java>` in the terminal(output will be displayed in Terminal tab)

Or install the code runner extension which is available in VS Code Marketplace (that would display results in output tab easily)